# Using AJAX post data to php page for mysqli prepared statement

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli

Good day!

In a first page I have a form:

```
inside the index.php
<form>
    <input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword">
    <input type="text" name="bodytypeid" id="bodytypeid">
</form>
```

Here is the div that shows the value of the updated table:

```
inside the index.php
<div id="result" class="table-responsive"></div>
```

And this script sends the whole form data to my php page:

```
inside the index.php
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('form').change(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Prevent Default Submission
        $.ajax({
            url: 'inventory_system/queryall.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success:function(html)
            {
              $('#result').html(html);
            }
        })
    });

    $('form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // Prevent Default Submission
        $.ajax({
            url: 'inventory_system/queryall.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success:function(html)
            {
              $('#result').html(html);
            }           
        })  
    });
});
```

And here is my php page:

```
inside the queryall.php
$keyword = $_POST['keyword'];
echo $keyword;

$sql = mysqli_prepare($conn,"SELECT inventorynum, itemyear, bodytypeid, chassisnum, accessories 
                             FROM inventoryitems 
                             WHERE inventorynum=?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql,"s",$keyword);

mysqli_stmt_execute($sql);
mysqli_stmt_store_result($sql); 
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($sql, $s_inventorynum, $s_itemyear, $s_bodytypeid, $s_chassisnum, $s_accessories);
$num_results = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($sql);

while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($sql)){ 
    echo "Hey";?>
    <tr style="border-style: 1px solid; border-color:black;">
        <td style="border-style:solid; border-color:black;"> <?php echo $s_inventorynum; ?> </td>
        <td style="border-style:solid; border-color:black;"> <?php echo $s_itemyear; ?> </td>
        <td style="border-style:solid; border-color:black;"> <?php echo $s_bodytypeid; ?> </td>
        <td style="border-style:solid; border-color:black;"> <?php echo $s_chassisnum; ?> </td>
        <td style="border-style:solid; border-color:black;"> <?php echo $s_accessories; ?> </td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

As you can see, I have tried to echo the value of the $keyword to test it, and it's working fine, the problem is when I try to run it in my mysqli prepared statement, it's not working. Why is it that I can echo the value but can't use it in my prepared statement? Am I missing something?

Note: My connection to the database is working fine since if I try to remove the WHERE statement, the page would show the whole data from the database.

Note: I updated my code and edited my question now.

Please help.

Comment: I forgot to mention, my fields in the first page is inside the form, it's like this.

<form>
<input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword">
<input type="text" name="bodytypeid" id="bodytypeid">
</form>

Comment: can you tell me little about what error does it give when you use the where statement in prepare statement

Comment: Hi! There is no error specified, it only does not show any data. But when I remove the WHERE statement, it will show data.

Comment: what is the type of this field inventorynum

Comment: inventorynum = varchar in my database

Comment: you want to take out the exact record or multiple records using the query

Comment: may be you don't provide the exact keyword that is in the records for the where clause and that's why it don't load up anything. If it is like search kinda thing. You need to use like query

Comment: anyway, I have already tried sending it using a submit button, and it works. I'm confuse why if I try sending it through ajax, the value will be sent but can't be read in the prepared statement.

Comment: I'm actually trying to type the exact text sample in my field, but it's still not working. I'm just trying to take out the exact record, so when my prepared statement starts working, I'll just expand the code use like and other filters for my fields.

Comment: When you did it without ajax, and provided the same keyword, did it pick up records?

Comment: Yup. Without ajax, using the usual submit button, I was able to load the records, with the same prepared statement I showed above.

Comment: If the `$keyword` value is actually being echo'd correctly before you use it in the bind_param... it should be going into the statement. The only two causes for *nothing to be returned* would be: A) the total query didn't result in any records found, or B) there is a mysql error that you are not displaying (use `mysqli_error($sql);`). - Also remove the `mysqli_stmt_store_result`, and don't forget to use the `mysqli_stmt_fetch` after your `mysqli_stmt_bind_result` (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php)

Comment: Yup, I did use the following, here is how I fetch the data, this is just the sample.

while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($sql)) { 
  echo $s_inventorynum . '<br/>'; 
                echo $s_itemyear . '<br/>';
                echo $s_bodytypeid . '<br/>';
  echo $s_chassisnum . '<br/>';
  echo $s_accessories . '<br/>';
}

Comment: Please add your first comment code and that comment code to your question. I'd edit your question, but someone locked up the review process with a rejection.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit now.

Comment: I have updated my question and code now, please check it. Thanks guys! I hope it will help you determine the problem easier.

Comment: $sql = mysqli_prepare($conn,"SELECT ...WHERE inventorynum=?");
$sql->mysqli_stmt_bind_param("s",$keyword);

The sample shows  $sql = mysqli_prepare... returns a prepared statement object. This object has a bind_param method in which you call thusly:
$sql->bind...

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT ... (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sssd', $code, $language, $official, $percent);

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: I'm just thinking wether it's the php page who has the problem or the ajax?

Answer (score 0):

mysqli_prepare returns a prepared statement object. This object contains a method by which you can bind_param

Your code should look something like this:

```
$query = 'select * from table where column = ?';
$sql = mysqli_prepare($query);
$sql->bind_param('s',$value);
```

this should do it.